# How can I split the standard Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line

I would like to have several terminals in the same window. I know I can have tabs, but with them we can't see two terminals at a time.

I know Terminator is another terminal able to do this, but I really like the standard terminal.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I do not know how to split, but you can launch 2 terminals at the same time

Comment: Are you meaning 'gnome-terminal' as the standard terminal?   If so, what features are you missing when you run terminator?   (I used both of these, but I love terminator.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not with the standard terminal. There are, however, a number of applications that you can install that will extend your terminal to allow for it, called multiplexers. [Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) and [Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) are two of the most common.

Answer (score 15):

Use terminator / termssh

`apt-get install terminator` # for GNOME but works fine on KDE.

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/termssh

wrote this to automate server connections either through autodiscovery or text file 4 -8 windows per tab

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question but maybe someone could find this useful.

There is a package [splitvt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/splitvt.1.html) that let you split the default Ubuntu terminal.

It can be installed in the usual way:

```
sudo apt-get install splitvt
```

and then just type `splitvt`.

From its manpage:

> This program splits the screen into two windows, one above the other, and runs a shell  in
>          each  one.  The default shell is taken from the SHELL environment variable, or /bin/csh if
>          SHELL isn't in the environment, but another shell can be specified on the command line.

Comment: Good, but worth noting that it loses some color, e.g. the prompt or when `vim` editing.

Answer (score 5):

I personally use Tilix

`sudo apt-get install tilix`

[image]

Comment: What should I do after the installation?

Comment: You open it like a normal program, and it appears in your Applications.

Answer (score 3):

Like Shauna suggests, GNU Screen among other tools will let you do this. It also comes with a host of other features which can be very useful (like keeping your programs running on a remote shell even after you have disconnected, so that you can re-connect to the session later).

If you decide to try any of these tools out, I suggest you look a little bit further than your initial needs requires you too, as the rewards will be immense.

Comment: Does screen let you split the viewable session, as opposed to making switchable session, tabs, etc.?

Comment: Yes. You can split the session vertically. I think horizontally should be possible as well, but I've never tried.

You can also simultaneously use the screen-session among several SSH sessions, so you can have multiple people working in the same screen. Great for remote assistance and collaboration with shell-problems.

Screen is really a fantastic utility.

Comment: I just tried Screen and unfortunately I am not able to use my splited terminals. I can move the focus to them using Ctrl+A tab but onec there typing anything doesn't show up on the screen. May be you know why ? Moreover, it seems impossible to split a window both horizontaly and vertically at the same time, isn't it ?

Comment: after tweeking I am able to do all I want with Screen and Tmux. A little bit tricky to get started, but seems very nice. Have fun and thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Very interesting commands using `tmux`:

`sudo apt install tmux`

`tmux`

`Ctrl+b "` Split current pane horizontally into two panes

`Ctrl+b %` Split current pane vertically into two panes

`Ctrl+b o` Go to the next pane

`Ctrl+b ;` Toggle between the current and previous pane

`Ctrl+b x` Close the current pane

`Ctrl+b d` keep your terminal running in background (you can close the terminal even if a socket is running.

`Ctrl+b w` list your panes (e.g. after reopening the terminal)

`Ctrl+b [` Activate scroll. Use ESC to exit.

For more options you can see here: https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/171177/226614